# AngularJS rendering html tag as string

Tags: angularjs

There is `<ul> <li>..</li> </ul>` tag which contains a product description.
I used `ngSanitize` dependency but it did not work. I also tried `ng-bind-html`,  `$sce.trustAsHtml()` but it is not working. Result is rendering the tag itself as string like `<ul><li>something</li></ul>`

I am using angular 1.4.

On browser console it is printing like:

```
&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Experience subject to availablity&lt;/li&gt;
```

And on HTML page it is printing like:

`<ul> <li> Experience subject to availablity</li>......`

First I tried sanitize dependacy with html-bind-unsafe

```
var app = angular.module('frogo-app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap','ngRoute', 'ngSanitize']); 
app.controller('contactController', function($scope, $http, myservice) {
   $scope.ysk = data from server;
         ......
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-bind-html="ysk"></div>
```

Secondly I tried

```
 app.controller('contactController', function($scope, $http, $sce, myservice) {
   $scope.ysk =$sce.trustAsHtml($scope.you_should_know);
     ......
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-bind-html="ysk"></div>
```

Third I tried

```
app.filter('unsafe', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml;});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-bind-html="ysk | unsafe"></div>
```

Comment: _What_ is your question actually? _What_ do you want to achieve? _What_ does not work as expected?

Comment: you want to display the html code in your page or you want to render it ?

Comment: I have to render product description as a list. So I am storing it as string in database in a single column.
But angular is printing the tag itselft. <ul><li>my data here<li>..
It is treating <ul</li>... as string.
I tried <div ng-bind-html="ysk"></div>
i tied different thing LIKE : ngSanitize dependacy, 
$scope.ysk =$sce.trustAsHtml($scope.you_should_know); 
app.filter('unsafe', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml;});

Answer (score 0):

I use this filter :

```
  /**
   * to interpret html code in the view ( otherwise it display the code without interpret it )
   *
   * usage : <span ng-bind-html="value | unsafe"></span>
   */
  var interfaceApp = angular.module('interfaceApp', []); 
  interfaceApp.filter('unsafe', function ($sce) {
     return function (val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
     };
  });
```

and call it the html view like this :

```
 <span ng-bind-html="value | unsafe"> </span>
```

value is the data you want to disply contenaing html tag

Comment: I had to use these 2 lines of code in filter.
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(val, "text/html");
            var rval= doc.documentElement.textContent;

Now it is working.

Comment: i use it a lot as i paste it , strange. i think it's not good to modifiy or access dom as you do with "doc.documentElement.textContent"

Answer (score 0):

I could be totally wrong but it sounds like you are trying to evaluate a string containing HTML from a database query and render it as html...

You would want to do something like this:

In your template:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
    <div ng-bind-html="my_html | to_trusted"></div>
</div>
```

And in your js/controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

angular.module('myApp')
.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
$scope.my_html = '<label><b>Hello </b> <input type="text" value="world !">            </label>';
}
```

Some from your pseudo-code above with $scope.ysk you would use something like this in your template:

```
<li><span ng-bind-html="ysk | to_trusted"></span></li>
```